# How to connect to Siemens PLCs using dynamic connection parameters

Tags: node.js, node-red, plc, siemens

I am trying to create a project that allows to change connection parameters without project's edits. I get parameters from a file stored in my PC. I used file-in to read the file, a switch to read the correct row and a function to get the IP Address from the row. The problem is that I dont know how to set up the connection to PLC using these parameters. Thanks for any help.

[image: This is the current state of the project]

Comment: Connection to do what? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68470516/edit) the question to add a lot more details

Answer (score 0):

You can use Node Red S7:
https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-s7

Note! for this to work, you must permit Get/Put in the PLC and also set your data block to non-optimized, as per the documentation for this node.

In regard to specifying the connection details using your text file.

You configure the connection using an S7 Endpoint node.  Here is an example on the Siemens forum:
https://support.industry.siemens.com/tf//WW/en/posts/s7-communication-with-node-red-error-connecting-to-plc-error-read-econnreset/185729?page=0&pageSize=10

To determine how much you can parameterize the S7 Endpoint node using data from your configuration file, you're going to have to do some experimentation or contact the developer on Github, or both.  Start with a fixed S7 EndPoint node and then try to feed it different parameters.  What could help is to export the node as JSON to find out how it is parameterized.

Comment: Thanks for the asnwer. I tried to use S7 library but with that library you can't change dynamically the S7 endpoint. You can only use a fixed endpoint and . you can't neither read the IP/port from the text file. I need to change my endpoint configuration dynamically reading IP/port from the text file Regards

Comment: Then you have a harder job ahead of you.  If you must connect using S7 communication, you can expand Node Red S7 to include the functionality you require.  Or, if you are happy to use another type of communication (e.g. Modbus or OPC/UA), then the associated nodes may allow the configurability you want.  Here's an example of OPC UA <->S7-1500 communication https://www.automation.siemens.com/sce-static/learning-training-documents/tia-portal/advanced-communication/sce-092-303-opc-ua-s7-1500-node-red-en.pdf